# Retrieve full string of XElement with mixed content

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

Let's say I have the following content in an `XElement` object

```
<root>Hello<child>Wold</child></root>
```

If I use `XElement.ToString()`, this gives me

```
"<root xmnls="someschemauri">Hello<child>World</child></root>"
```

If I use XElement.Value, I will get

```
"Hello World"
```

I need to get

```
"Hello <child>World</child>"
```

What is the proper function to do this(if there is one)?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? The answers are different for .NET 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution for .NET 4

```
var result = String.Join("", rootElement.Nodes()).Trim();
```

---

Complete code (for .NET 3.5):

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse("<root>Hello<child>Wold</child></root>");
var nodes = rootElement.Nodes().Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray();
string result = String.Join("", nodes).Trim();
Console.WriteLine(result);
// writes "Hello<child>World</child>"
```

---

Fast solution without joining all nodes:

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse("<root>Hello<child>Wold</child></root>");
var reader = rootElement.CreateReader();
reader.MoveToContent();
string result = reader.ReadInnerXml();
```

Comment: @Magnum you are doing something wrong. There should not bee root node itself. Only nodes are joined.

Comment: I got the rootElement is derived from `XDocument.Root property.`, so I simply did `String.Join("", xDoc.Root.Nodes()).Trim()`; and the aforementioned output is what I got.

Comment: @Magnum then your `<root>` element is not `Root` of document. Select your `<root>` element instead

Comment: xElement.Nodes() does not return a string array, I can't use it in the String.Join function. I'm on .NET 3.5 btw

Comment: @Machinegon on .NET 4 String.Join works with IEnumerable. Btw call `.ToArray()` on .NET 3.5

Comment: this will do, I tough there was something easier than running a linq query thought.

Comment: @Machinegon I've added nice solution with simple `XmlReader` which you can create from element.

Comment: That's nice, what's the better solution regarding performance. This will get called quite often.

Answer (score 1):

This worked rather nicely:

```
//SOLUTION BY Nenad
var element = XElement.Parse("<root>Hello<child>World</child></root>");
string xml = string.Join("", element.DescendantNodes().Select(e => e.ToString()));
Debug.WriteLine(xml);
```

Final output: `Hello<child>Wold</child>World`

---

Try #3

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<root>Hello<child>World</child></root>");
XElement rootElement = xDoc.Root;
Debug.WriteLine(rootElement.Value + rootElement.FirstNode.ToString());
```

Comment: Or maybe [.Nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.nodes.aspx).ToString()?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I thought about that but his example is very simplistic so the nodes would return child nodes and not necessarily comments or otherwise no?  Since I don't know what his eventual xml file will look like, I used Descendants.

Comment: nah that's not it, it Nodes() and Descendant() gives me some weird stuff like System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+d__a
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+d__a instead of a tag and value

System.Xml.Linq.XContain

Comment: But, does Descendants return text?

Comment: No it does not, it returns a collection of XElement obviously.

Comment: @Machinegon Sorry, I'm about to update my answer, working on a full solution in a new solution I created.

Comment: Magnum, your answer would work in this specific example context but currently I dont have access to the XDocument object where I'm in my code. I must come up with something from the XElement

Comment: Put element.Nodes(), only direct children. "World" was duplicated at the end as it's deeper nested XText node. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
var element = XElement.Parse("<root>Hello<child>Wold</child></root>");
string xml = string.Join("", element.Nodes().Select(e => e.ToString()));
```

For .NET 3.5 (if that was the point of question):

```
var element = XElement.Parse("<root>Hello<child>Wold</child></root>");
string xml = string.Join("", element.Nodes().Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: This returns `"Hello<child>Wold</child>Wold"`, with unnecessary `Wold` and the end.

Comment: Fixed - Nodes(), not DescendandNodes().

Comment: Same question - how it differs from my answer?

Comment: Your first/main line is little bit akward. Why Trim? And doesn't work in .NET 3.5. You fixed it later too.

Comment: @Nenad first line was written before OP mentioned about 3.5 (see timeline). That's why code below fixed. Trim is needed for non-single line xml. Otherwise you will get empty lines at start and at end.

Comment: 1st - your answer was confusing (way you wrote it), 2nd - that Trim() would fix start and end of the string, but all child nodes would still have their white spaces, so what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

**Extension method** based on fastest know solution:

```
public static class XElementExtension
{
    public static string InnerXML(this XElement el) {
        var reader = el.CreateReader();
        reader.MoveToContent();
        return reader.ReadInnerXml();
    }
}
```

Then simple call it: `xml.InnerXML();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test this, but try:

```
var inners = from n in xelementVariableName.Nodes()
                       select n;
return String.Join(String,Empty, inners);
```

---

Tested:

```
public static string ReturnInnerXml()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<root>Hello<child>World</child></root>");
    var root = doc.Root;
    if (root == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No root");
    }

    var inners = from n in root.Nodes()
                 select n;
    return String.Join(String.Empty, inners);
}
```

This produces:

```
Hello<child>World</child>
```

Using .NET 4.0.

Comment: By that I assume you mean this : var inners = from element in xElement.Nodes() select element.ToString();return inners.Aggregate((content, next) => next + " " + content); and sadly it returns the root tag included

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
var element = XElement.Parse("<root>Hello<child>Wold</child></root>");
string xml = string.Join("", element.Nodes().Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Returns `Hello<child>Wold</child>` and works on .NET 3.5

Comment: How it differs from my answer?